Как сделать так, чтобы кнопки всегда находились в самых верхних углах?
Я пытаюсь это сделать, но все не понимаю как? Мне нужно, чтобы приложение могло изменять свой размер, но при этом все оставалось там, где и стоит, а не относительно всего окна стояло.
Layout'ы делают не совсем то что нужно
Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы кнопочки были там и всегда оставались там, независимо от изменений размера окна. 
А макеты это не то.... Не подходит.


Anonymous1245, покажите что вы уже пробовали сделать и расскажите подробнее что не так делают Layout'ы. Попробуйте показать на изображении то, что ва хотите получать.

@S.Nick Такс.... Ну. Да

Поставьте Horizontal spacer между кнопками и они будут закреплены к границам Layout-а. Точно также вертикальным Spacer-ом прижимаете горизонтальный Layout к верху окна

@gord1402 спасибо

Вы не внимательно прочитали то, о чем я вас спрашивал.
Попробуйте так:
q1594978.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>420</width>
    <height>364</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>50</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>50</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>byn1</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>50</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>50</width>
          <height>50</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>btn2</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string> </string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>420</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


